# when duplicate values found then

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, duplicates, case-when

I want to have a query that selects all duplicate values in a column. If those value meet the conditions then I'd like the query to return only those values.

```
Class    Student_ID  Location
Biology     511         4A
Biology     512         15B
Biology     513         15B
English     514         6A
Biology     521         6A
Spanish     522         6A
Spanish     523         15B
Chemistry   524         4A
English     531         15B
Biology     532         4A
Chemistry   534         4A
```

Select all duplicate values in the class column and if among those values there is location in both 4A and 15B then assign 1.

```
CASE WHEN count(class) > 1 AND (Location = '4A' AND Location = '15B') THEN 1
 ELSE 0 END
```

what is most important is how to select duplicate values as a group and then look at the condition (location must be 4A and 15B). So the query must first group the duplicated values from the class column and then see if within the group the values meet the condition of location. So for example we first group the class column we get 5x biology this is then seen as a group and then within this group if there exist one row with location 4A AND one row with location 15B then and only then assign value 1 for biology. Almost all the values in class column have duplicates.

**Desired Output**

```
Class       Location
Biology     1
Chemistry   0
English     0
Spanish     0
```

Comment: @DerrickMoeller sorry i meant Biology. I tried explaining it a little more. The issue is mainly selecting the duplicate values as a group. The size of the group is irrelevant the only thing that matters is that if within the group both location are present then assign 1.

Comment: @BobOutlook Sounds good, I'm pretty sure both myself and Tim have provided answers then.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Tim Schmelter's answer, you can also do this with a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT yt1.Class, IIF(COUNT(yt2.Class) > 0, 1, 0) AS IsMatch
FROM YourTable yt1
LEFT JOIN YourTable yt2 ON yt1.Location = '4A' AND yt2.Location = '15B' AND
                           yt2.Class = yt1.Class
GROUP BY yt1.Class
```